# django auto_add_now not working

Tags: python, django

I have a model in which error is thrown when ever i use `python manage.py syncdb`

At this line `createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)` and the error is

```
File "/home/vaibhav/TRAC/coupon-rest-api/couponRestApi/couponRestApiApp/models.py", line 18, in tags
  createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 660, in __init__
  Field.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_add_now'
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a typo, the correct is `auto_now_add` not `auto_add_now`.